# Install PHP 8 separately from PHP 7 - Centos 7

Tags: centos, php

My production Centos 7 machine is running PHP 7.4 but I 'd like to test code against PHP 8. Before a few days,in formatting a new server, I tried `yum-config-manager --enable remi-php8` but this broke the setup, for my PHP code had a TCPDF issue that wouldn't work in PHP 8, so I had to downgrade to PHP 7.4.

Is there anyway in Centos to have both versions and switch on demand ?so I can test but at the same time keep the working part intact.

Running over nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Software collections (SCL) are designed for parallel installation beside the system default version, thus allowing to run multiple versions simultaneously.

This is described in [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/), especially the switch to FPM for httpd users (as mod_php, used by default in CentOS 7), allow only a single version). Nginx users always use FPM.

In remi repository you can find PHP 5.6 to 8.0 as SCL.

For a proper installation, follow the [wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) (and choice "multiple versions").

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar goal, and went a slightly different way:

I wanted to be able to test with newer versions of PHP as well as the production version, and run testcases against them.

## Code centric Development environment

I started by using [vagrant](/questions/tagged/vagrant), which basically is a way of provisioning your VMs. the configuration is in code, in form of a [VagrantFile](https://github.com/JoSSte/BasicLamp). I liked the way this allowed me to set up completely equal environments, and bracnh off to test new versions of PHP without changing the rest of the system. The way I set it up, it basically maps your `src` folder to the vm, and you are off.
This also meant that any developer checking out the code will be able to spin up a development environment which is exactly the same as the one all the other developers are using.

## Going further

*This is a further development of the scenario I have described, and is essentially an alternative route*
After some iterations, and a desire to automate the testing, which meant spinning up a test environment when I needed to test, with the same specs as my prod environment, I decided to move to [docker](/questions/tagged/docker). the overhead is less, and it appears that docker is easier to run on different OSes, so essentially I did the same sort of thing in docker, which means that setting up CI/CD is easy since a lot of those tools have docker integrations built in.